# C++ - error: expected initializer before 'SortedPairsVector'

Tags: c++

I have the function definition bellow:

```
  template <class KEY, class VALUE>
  inline
  SortedPairsVector<KEY, VALUE>::value_type& 
  SortedPairsVector<KEY, VALUE>::operator[](int index) //Error Here
  {
      return d_data[index].data();
  }
```

The following error occurs on the line indicated:

```
  error: expected initializer before 'SortedPairsVector'
```

I'm sure the answer is really simple, but I'm new to C++ and I can't seem to spot it. What is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
typename SortedPairsVector<KEY, VALUE>::value_type&
```

instead of

```
SortedPairsVector<KEY, VALUE>::value_type&
```